# AnimatedVectorDrawable - reset() is not working properly on some Huawei devices

Tags: android, animation, android-vectordrawable, huawei-mobile-services, animatedvectordrawable

We use `AnimatedVectorDrawable.reset()` to reset the animation to its initial state. This works well on most of the devices. While testing we noticed that on some Huawei devices when `reset()` is called the animation starts running.

Reproduced on these Huawei devices:

- ANE-LX1 - Android 8.0.0, EMIU 8.0.0
- LYA-L29 - Android 10, EMIU 10.0.0

Any ideas what can I do to fix the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix the problem I updated the animation to end in the state it starts. This allowed me to stop using `AnimatedVectorDrawable.reset()`.

Section "Stale state" from [this article](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/re-animation-7869722af206) helped me resolve the problem. Here is the important part of the section:

> On older devices I found that their ‘state’ wasn’t being reset (to how it was defined in the VectorDrawable) on each loop.
>   ...
>   To fix this I added a zero length animation to set properties to their expected value at the start of each loop so that they’re ready to be animated e.g.:

```
<set>
    <objectAnimator
        android:propertyName="fillAlpha"
        android:valueFrom="0"
        android:valueTo="0"
        android:duration="0" />
    <objectAnimator
        android:propertyName="fillAlpha"
        android:valueFrom="0"
        android:valueTo="1"
        android:startOffset="1900"
        android:duration="60"
        android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/linear" />
</set>
```

This is the part that resets the animation to its initial state:

```
    <objectAnimator
        android:propertyName="fillAlpha"
        android:valueFrom="0"
        android:valueTo="0"
        android:duration="0" />
```

`valueFrom` and `valueTo` are equal to `valueFrom` in the second `objectAnimator`.